# Integrating a AdMob banner ad on a android surface view for an android game

Tags: java, android, admob

I am developing an android game. The context view extends the surface view class. I am attempting to put a banner on the bottom of the screen. I have set up the Google AdMob SDK using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk). I have added the AdView to the layout and loaded a test ad using [another guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner).

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-1042328490971088~5397056328");

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

When I run this code no ad is displayed at all while my game continues to function properly. My thought is that perhaps the ad is there but is not visible because the game view takes up the entire screen. I would appreciate it if someone could help me ensure that my banner ad is overlayed onto the canvas or the canvas is shrunk to accommodate the ad.

Also here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haakamaujla.myfirstgame">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Stunty Skys"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through posts I found the answer to my question:

```
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Apparently, this forces the ad to show and it does not consistently show otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the layout for your banner ad.
Try this and it will work perfectly:

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    // Create a banner ad
    AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    // Create an ad request.
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

    // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
    adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

    View gameView = (new GameView(this));

    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(mAdView, adParams);

    // Start loading the ad.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

    setContentView(layout);


    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Enjoy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Sorry bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });
```